# MediaPlayer.SeekTo(int) throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, service, media-player, illegalstateexception

Sometimes I get IllegalStateException thrown by MediaPlayer.SeekTo(int)
The MediaPlayer runs in a Service, and a call the SeekTo(int) like this:

```
public void seekTo(int value)
{
if (mp != null && !(value <= -1)) {
mp.seekTo(value);
}
}
```

Comment: Firstly why would you use `!(value <= -1)`? That's basically the same as `(value >= 0)` - sorry, it just seems a very strange way of doing things. Secondly, have you checked the documentation for `MediaPlayer` and the `seekTo(...)` method? It will throw an exception if it's in Idle, Initialized, Stopped or Error state. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalStateException` is thrown to prevent programming errors such as calling `prepare()`, `prepareAsync()`, or one of the overloaded `setDataSource` methods in an invalid state.

An `IllegalStateException` is thrown if `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()` is called in any other state.

Although the asynchronuous `seekTo(int)` call returns right way, the actual seek operation may take a while to finish, especially for audio/video being streamed. When the actual seek operation completes, the internal player engine calls a user supplied `OnSeekComplete.onSeekComplete()` if an `OnSeekCompleteListener` has been registered beforehand via `setOnSeekCompleteListener(OnSeekCompleteListener)`.
Please note that `seekTo(int)` can also be called in the other states, such as `Prepared`, `Paused` and `PlaybackCompleted`  state.

This data is all covered here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
In fact I directly quoted it.

You should be able to handle any errors encountered using an `OnErrorListener()`.

You can find more about an `OnErrorListener()` here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

In the error listener you will:

1. Receive the error.
2. Determine the type of error.
3. Handle the error to rectify the situation without crashing.